# Showing 1 and not all out database

Tags: php, html, css, sql, foreach

I got this problem with my website (builded in php(pdo)). If I want here 1 thing out of the database I get all of them and not just 1. As you can see the 2 "onderwerp" are getting showed but I only wanted 1 of them for example the first one.

The code for this is:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="well dash-box">
   <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12</h2>
    <h5><a href="https://google.nl"> hoi</a></h5>
     <?php
      $toppics = $app->get_topics();
      $i = 4;
      foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
      echo '<li><a href="#section' . $i++ . '">' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</a></li>';
      }
      ?>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And now I want it to show 1 not all of them but I dont get it done

[image: The 2 things with the dots are out of the database]

[image: The database where the things behind the dots came from]

```
 public function get_topics(){
        $getTopic = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC");
        $this->database->bind(":ledenpagina_id", $_SESSION['ledenpagina_id']);
        $topics = $this->database->resultset();

        return $topics;

}
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: My expected result is that it wil only show `Tag werkt niet` and not `Testen forum`, so I want to show only the first one

Comment: What is your **get_topics** method? Why not have a **get_first_topic** method returning what you want? Or simply (but dirty) do not loop over your topics.

Comment: @PierreC. added the **get_topics** function in my question

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
      $toppics = $app->get_topics();
      $i = 4;
      $j = 0;
      foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
      if($j >= 1) continue;
      echo '<li><a href="#section' . $i++ . '">' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</a></li>';
      $j++;
      }
      ?>
```

It will skip all the iteration after first one and will only print first value. Although this is not a standard solution you should consider setting a limit 1 in your DB Query. But if you can't do that this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

From the **get_topics** method you provided, the best solution would be to create a new method and add the `LIMIT 1` property to the SQL request.

```
SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select only one latest record right ?
So you need to make changes into SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

LIMIT 1 will return only one record.